# Instrumenting R programs using intel-pin

Tags: r, intel-pin

I am instrumenting R programs using pinatrace.so tool to generate trace for read and write memory instructions. What I observe is that multiple #eof statements get printed in the trace file at different places(which should have been actually get printed only at the end of the trace). Also, the immediate next line after #eof gets distorted and is not printed properly.

I am invoking R shell and my R program using the following command:

../../../pin -follow_execv -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so -- /home/R-3.5.3./bin/R -f hello.R

The trace file gets printed as shown:

0  0x7ffc812cd1c8

1  0x7ffc812cd1c8

0  0x7f7f8555ee78

#eof

f6971ce8

1 0x6f4518

0 0x7ffc171a0b70

.....

.....

1 0x7ffc6da8f078

0 0x7f7c38786e78

#eof

ffc171a07c8

0 0x6f4e30

0 0x6ff918

What is wrong with this instrumentation?

Answer (score 2):

When Pin is invoked with the follow_execv knob, it will create a new copy of itself in every child process that is created. The new copy is not aware that another copy is running in the parent or at all. See [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/group__CHILD__PROCESS__API.html):

> If -follow_execv is enabled and the user has not registered to get a notification, Pin will be injected into child/exec-ed process with the same command line as of current process.

If the Pintool wasn't created with -follow_execv in mind, all copies of the Pintool will normally write to the same file. This will create strange artifacts such as what you're seeing, as different processes write to the same file and terminate it while other processes are writing after the terminator.

The simplest solution is to add a PID suffix to the file, another option is to use the Follow Child Process API (linked above) to determine which subprocess is the actual R program you want to trace. Finally, R may have support for instrumentation which you could use to instrument the program itself.